# Is this possible to restric users to view a document only when its been approved?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

We have got a Basic document library with OOB 'Approve-share point 2010' workflow. We want users to see the document only once its been approved (owner and approver can view it).

I have been playing around with different settings in share point but no luck so far.

At the moment, if someone from contributor group uploads a document then its visible to everyone even its not been approved yet.

Note: We don't use version and checkout settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need the publishing workflow which routes content for approval in the same way as the approval workflow does, except that it’s designed for Enterprise Content Management sites with publishing features enabled.

So note that the publishing workflow is only available in SharePoint Server 2010. You must enable the publishing feature.

For clarification: You use an approval workflow for things like approval of an expense report. This is totally something else then publishing content with a publishing workflow. The misunderstanding is that you could think you approve something to publish and indeed that is true but you need it to do this with a publishing workflow.

Comment: How does publishing workflow works? If user A uploads a document then user B gets an email to aprrove it. At this point where should user B go to approve a document? Does he need to approve a task or he can right click on a document and click approve? or it works differently?

Comment: He must approve a task... workflows are mostly task based. Just look at the following link : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx

Comment: I have just tried the Publishing workflow and other users can still view a document even though its not been approved yet.

Comment: Do i need to set content approval to yes in version settings?

Comment: Yes Hanah, you need to. Step by step instructions: http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=920

Comment: If i just use built in content approval process by setting content approval to yes and select option 'only users who can approve it and authors' in version settings without using a OOB Approval workflow then it will okay but Approver won't get an alert Approval email as OOB Approval workflow does.

Comment: I think this link helps creating a email notification for approvers.http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-example-send-a-notification-message-HA010182908.aspx